# How to update data values (i.e., image width, height) of RecycleView embedded in Scatter while zooming?

Tags: python, kivy

Couldn't find any details for RecycleView embedded in Scatter widget. Though there are several issues related touch in case RecycleView (or ScrollView in general) is embedded in Scatter, but in my specific case the issue is while the image is scaled the properties like image width/height are not changed (the expected behavior of Scatter) and hence the RecycleView layout is not updated. For this reason the horizontal scrolling is not possible. Please look into the below code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import sp, dp
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from PIL import Image as PILImage

MY_APP_KV_LANG = """
#:import ScrollEffect kivy.effects.scroll.ScrollEffect
<RootLayout>:
    size_hint: 1, 1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos        
    DocLayoutScat:
        id: docscat
        DocumentWidget:
            id: rv
            viewclass: 'Image'
            key_size: 'size'
            effect_cls: ScrollEffect
            scroll_type: ['content']
            bar_width: 0
            cols: 1
            width: docscat.width
            height: docscat.height
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                id: rvbox
                spacing: dp(10)
                padding: dp(10)
                cols: rv.cols
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: None, None
                height: self.minimum_height
                width: self.minimum_width
                default_size_hint: 1, None
"""

class RootLayout(FloatLayout):
    pass

class DocLayoutScat(Scatter):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if 'auto_bring_to_front' not in kwargs:
            self.auto_bring_to_front = False
        super(DocLayoutScat, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if touch.is_double_tap:
            if 1.0 >= self.scale >= 0.99:
                anim = Animation(scale=2., duration=0.2, transition='in_quad')
                anim.start(self)
            else:
                anim = Animation(scale=1., duration=0.2, transition='out_quad')
                anim.start(self)

        return super(DocLayoutScat, self).on_touch_up(touch)

class DocumentWidget(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DocumentWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        pil_image = PILImage.open('test3.jpg')
        self.data = [{'source': 'test3.jpg', 'width': Window.size[0] - dp(20), 'height': (Window.size[0] - dp(20)) * pil_image.size[1] / pil_image.size[0], 'size_hint_x': None, 'size_hint_y': None, 'allow_stretch': True, 'keep_ratio': True} for x in range(3)]

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(MY_APP_KV_LANG)
        return RootLayout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

I have tried to change the image width/height with the scale value, but this doubles the effect of increasing width/height. Is there any way to update the data properties of RecycleView along with scaling so that horizontal scrolling would be possible when zooming/scaling?

Comment: any update from anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found way to implement pinch-zoom without adding scatter widget as the scatter doesn't update the width & height for data hence scrolling dimensions are also not updated. The below is the implementation without scatter. The zoom works with touch anchor point. It's not ideal as the animations are not smooth.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import sp, dp
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from PIL import Image as PILImage
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.graphics.transformation import Matrix
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import PopMatrix, PushMatrix, Translate

MY_APP_KV_LANG = """
#:import ScrollEffect kivy.effects.scroll.ScrollEffect
<RootLayout>:
    size_hint: 1, 1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos        
    DocumentWidget:
        id: rv
        viewclass: 'Image'
        key_size: 'size'
        effect_cls: ScrollEffect
        scroll_type: ['content']
        bar_width: 0
        cols: 1
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            id: rvbox
            spacing: dp(10)
            padding: dp(10)
            cols: rv.cols
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: None, None
            height: self.minimum_height
            width: self.minimum_width
            default_size_hint: 1, None
"""

class RootLayout(FloatLayout):
    pass

class DocumentWidget(RecycleView):
    scale = NumericProperty(1.)
    scroll_y1 = NumericProperty(0.)
    scroll_y2 = NumericProperty(0.)
    delta_scy = NumericProperty(0.)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DocumentWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        pil_image = PILImage.open('test3.jpg')
        self.data = [{'source': 'test3.jpg', 'width': Window.size[0] - dp(20), 'height': (Window.size[0] - dp(20)) * pil_image.size[1] / pil_image.size[0], 'size_hint_x': None, 'size_hint_y': None, 'allow_stretch': True, 'keep_ratio': True} for x in range(3)]
        self.data_initial = [{'width': Window.size[0] - dp(20), 'height': (Window.size[0] - dp(20)) * pil_image.size[1] / pil_image.size[0]} for x in range(3)]
        self.bind(on_scale = self.on_scale)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            if touch.is_double_tap:
                if 1.0 >= self.scale >= 0.99: 
                    self.scroll_y1 = self.scroll_y
                    self.delta_scy = Window.size[1] - touch.pos[1] - dp(10)
                    def _prg(*args):
                        self.scroll_x = (touch.pos[0] * self.scale) / (self.data[0]["width"] + dp(20))
                        self.scroll_y = self.scroll_y1 - self.scroll_y1 * self.delta_scy * (self.scale - 1) / (self.layout_manager.size[1] - Window.size[1])                    
                        self.scroll_y2 = self.scroll_y
                    anim = Animation(scale=2, duration=0.2, transition='in_quad')
                    anim.bind(on_progress=_prg)
                    anim.start(self)
                else:
                    def _prg(*args):
                        self.scroll_y = (self.scroll_y2 - self.scroll_y1) * self.scale + 2 * self.scroll_y1 - self.scroll_y2 
                    anim = Animation(scale=1, duration=0.2, transition='out_quad')
                    anim.bind(on_progress=_prg)
                    anim.start(self)
        return super(DocumentWidget, self).on_touch_up(touch)

    def on_scale(self, *args):
        for x in range(3): 
            self.data[x]["height"] = self.data_initial[x]["height"] * self.scale
            self.data[x]["width"] = self.data_initial[x]["width"] * self.scale
        self.refresh_from_data()

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(MY_APP_KV_LANG)
        return RootLayout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```